# Promote previous build

Tags: heroku

I would like to promote from staging to promotion a build that got executed by Heroku, but never made it to production.

I can't use the rollback feature since that build was never promoted.

The use case is the following. My company has a staging app and a production app. The staging app auto deploys from `master`. I have pushed a commit to `master`, which triggered a build on staging. I tested my build.

While I did so, someone else pushed a commit to `master`, which triggered another build. That second build completed. That other person has not yet tested their changes, so I can't promote their build. I would like to only promote mine.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to rollback your staging app temporarily? That way, you can promote the tested changes. After, you can redeploy current master after the second commit has been tested, and promote the staging build to production.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While this works, I find it pretty disruptive to the other person currently testing their changes. I am looking for a solution to apply more or less every day, thus as smooth as possible